# How to interpret this error message: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a table: numTable that looks like this:
[image]

Now I want to find outiers for each of these columns. Please see my code below:

```
for (i in names(numTable)) {
  #calculate mean and std for each column
  meanValue <- mean(numTable[,i], na.rm=TRUE)
  stdValue<-sd(numTable[,i],na.rm=TRUE)
  #Sum up number of outliers for each column
  print(paste("there are",sum(abs(numTable[,i]-meanValue)>3*stdValue,na.rm =  
TRUE),"outliers in the column",i))
 }
```

But I get error message:

```
Error in is.data.frame(x) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I fixed this problem by adding `numTable<-as.data.frame(numTable)` at the beginning. 
Could you please tell me why I have to add this line for my code to work? Does it have something to do with difference between tbl and data.frame?
Thanks.

Comment: What is `class(classTable)` before you converted it to `data.frame`?

Comment: I get this result `[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"` after I run `class(numT)`. I am not sure if it is a tbl_df or tbl or data.frame.

Comment: It is all of them. In this case, I think Hayden has the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a hidden argument in square bracket indexing `data.frames` called `drop`, which defaults to `TRUE`, and says if you index one column, try to simplify the result to a vector. See `?'['`.

However Hadley Wickham believes this this is unpredictable behaviour, so `tbl`s enforce `drop = FALSE`.

If you wanted to keep using `tbl`s and avoid converting to a `data.frame`. You could use `dplyr::pull` to extract a single column as a vector. i.e:

```r
is.vector(data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10])[, 1])
#> [1] TRUE
is.vector(data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10])[, 1, drop = FALSE])
#> [1] FALSE
is.vector(dplyr::tibble(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10])[, 1])
#> [1] FALSE
is.vector(dplyr::pull(dplyr::tibble(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10]), 1))
#> [1] TRUE
```